# Java Method to find uppercase letters and numbers in a String

Tags: java, string, methods, numbers, uppercase

I'm fairly new to java and was wondering if there is a method that finds the uppercase letters in a string and also if there is method that finds the numbers in a string. 
Thank you

Comment: yes there is but it depends on what you want to do with those characters which determines which of the many ways to do this is best.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: Regex may help you.  You could also create your own method to manual look for these

Comment: What exactly your requirement is?

Comment: A simple Google search will answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957944/search-for-capital-letter-in-string

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a proprietary method.
You can use regular expression, or loop over letters in string and extract you need.

See some code here:
[Extract digits from string - StringUtils Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974033/extract-digits-from-string-stringutils-java)
[Extract digits from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

Please search first, before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) doesn't offer a method to do that *specifically*. You'll have to code it yourself using some of the methods `String` provides.

If you're a begginer, I'd suggest taking a look at [Manipulating Strings in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), also [how do loops work in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), and the `Character` class (specifically the `isDigit()` and `isUpperCase()` methods).

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
    for(Character c : s.toCharArray()){
        if(c.toString().toUpperCase().equals(c.toString())){
            System.out.println("Upper case");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Lower case");
        }
    }
```

So we convert String to character array, iterate over it and in each iteration we compare itself with it's the upper case to check what case is used.

and for finding number you can do something like below

```
    for(Character c : s.toCharArray()){

        try{
            Integer.parseInt(c.toString());
            System.out.println("Integer Identified");
        }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println("Not an integer");
        }
    }
```

For number simply parse String using `Integer.parseInt()`. If it is able to successfully parse then it is a number or if exception is thrown then it is not a number.

Comment: 1.  Explain what the code does.  2.  Answer the rest of his questions.

Comment: Updated the answer with explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't specified any plans for further processing the String, you can use something like this to find uppercase and digits:

```
public class Extraction {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "This is a test containing S and 10";
    for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            System.out.println("Digit: " + c);
        }
        else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            System.out.println("Uppercase letter: " + c);
        }
    }
  }
}
```